# Why is my dependent package not resolved?

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2015, nuget, nuget-package

I have a package dependency situation as follows:
Error:

Attempting to gather dependency information for package 'PkgB.2.0.414' with respect to project 'test Nuget Package Usage', targeting '.NETFramework,Version=v4.5'
Attempting to resolve dependencies for package 'PkgB.2.0.414' with DependencyBehavior 'Lowest'
Unable to resolve dependency 'PkgC.1.0.0'. Source(s) used: 'nuget.org', 'Company Package source', 'Local testing', 'Microsoft and .NET', 'Microsoft Visual Studio Offline Packages'.

Situation A:
PkgA=>PkgC

Situation B:
PkgB=>PkgA=>PkgC

When I install situation A it works. When I install situation B it works. But if I install A then B it fails to find Pkg C even though its already installed and working fine.

Keep in mind the following environment:

These are all packages that install fine individually and separately.
This problem **only** happens using a NuGet feed server.
I don't have this problem using a package share as the source of installation.

Sources:
I've looked at NuGet documentation for versioning and the nearest algorithm, but I don't see how I would be violating it.

https://docs.nuget.org/ndocs/consume-packages/dependency-resolution#dependency-resolution-in-nuget-3-x

And I don't see how specifying versions would matter either.
https://docs.nuget.org/ndocs/create-packages/dependency-versions#dependency-versions

My own conclusion:

It seems like the issue is in the feed server and how it finds the dependencies. I'm looking at the NuGet.Server source on git but haven't noticed anything yet. I'll probably end up bringing down the source and figuring it out.

Shouldn't this situation work regardless of the type of feed source?

Edit:

This is a private nuget feed and private nugets that aren't in any repo that I can share publicly.

I used the version >= notation referenced here to build the reference tree throughout the situations.

```
<!-- Accepts any version 6.1 and above -->
<dependency id="ExamplePackage" version="6.1" />
```

Comment: Are PkgA, PkgB and PkgC all dependent packages or they has some dependencies relationship between them? If possible, please share these packages here (not your nuget feed) to help us reproduce this issue.

Comment: Wendy I listed the dependencies, above, but I wasn't specific about them being dependencies. The Situation A: PkgA=>PkgC

Situation B: PkgB=>PkgA=>PkgC are the dependency lines as well as the installation situations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like it was a combination of Nuget cache's locally.

I execute the following commands to clear them.

VS2015 kept complaining about installing the same package version and since I'd been messing around with 1.0.0.0 vs 1.0.0 versioning this makes some sense.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/consume-packages/managing-the-nuget-cache

I issued each of the commands and with a reboot was able to completely empty the caches. It now works and I no longer get the problem.

Comment: Thanks for sharing your workaround here. Please mark your answer later. It is benefit to other communities who has the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with your opinion that “this situation work regardless of the type of feed source”.

For the install A then B it fails: Please confirm whether the constraint of dependences version of Pkg A,Pkg C in Situation B are consistent with Situation A. If the dependences Pkg A, Pkg C with high version in Situation A install first, then install Situation B with low version dependences, the installation will be fail. The same issue: [Is there an OData dependency graph somewhere](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41023266/is-there-an-odata-dependency-graph-somewhere)?.

For the feed source: please check the packages version of Pkg A and Pkg B in the  NuGet feed server are consistent with Share package folder.

If this issue persist, just share us the NuGet packages ID, I will repro it in my side:)